# Make search query where only the most matched words should return the post_ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've created a form with pick and drop inputs so when user enters delhi airport as pick location and agra as drop location then it should return post_ID = 2 but i've made a query using `WHERE LIKE` which results all ID's having word "Delhi" in post_title.

Can anyone here help me in getting accurate result?

Thanks in advance.

For product 1:

```
post_ID = 1
column name | Value
post_title | Delhi, Agra //syntax pick location, drop location
post_name | delhi-agra //syntax pick location-drop location
```

For product 2:

```
post_ID = 2
column name | Value
post_title | Delhi Airport, Agra
post_name | delhi-airport-agra
```

Here Delhi, Delhi Airport and Agra are the combinations of woocommerce variations.

Query:

```
global $wpdb;

$q1 = $wpdb->get_results("select * from table_name where post_type='product_variation' and post_title like '%".$pick[0]."%, %".$drop[0]."%'");
```

I know this query will be changed but I am not sure which method should be used to get the ID as I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
$search_query = $_POST['the_search_query']; //... Get search query, be sure to validate

//... Connect to Database, then:
$results = array();
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT item_id, other_stuff FROM tablename WHERE MATCH(item_title) AGAINST(? IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) LIMIT 5");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $search_query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if (($n_res = $stmt->num_rows) > 0): // $n_res can tell you how many results are found
    $stmt->bind_result($item_id, $other_stuff);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()):
        $results[] = array($item_id, htmlspecialchars($other_stuff));
    endwhile;
    $stmt->free_result();
else:
    echo 'error';
endif;
$stmt->close();
$dbc->close();
```

Show Results Example

```
<?php
if ($results):
    ?><ul><?php
    foreach($results as $r):
        ?><li><?php echo $r[0].' '.$r[1]; ?></li><?php
    endforeach;
    ?></ul><?php
endif;
?>
```

When using MATCH() AGAINST(), you may have to add a FULLTEXT KEY to your table, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE something (
    ...,
    ...,
    FULLTEXT KEY items_i_want_to_match (item_title, other_stuff)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```